# trouble parsing text file with C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a .txt file containing a list of about 200 numbers with one on each line and I'm trying to parse it with C++ but I'm facing some issues -- here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("input.txt");
    
    // check for error
    if(file.good())
        cout << "opened!";
    else
    {
        cerr << "issue" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (file >> n)
    {
      cout << n;
    }
    
    file.close();
}
```

Basically I'm trying to input these elements into an integer array (separate from this) but I have trouble reading the .txt file for some reason as it always results in "issue". Also, when I try for example to output multiple numbers from this file

```
int a,b,c;
file >> a >> b >> c;
cout << a << b << c ;
```

it always results in (seemingly) random numbers being printed. I thought it was a problem with the location of my input file but after recreating a project and changing the locations of my files I still can't seem to fix this. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Its returning 'issue' and reading garbage numbers because you are failing to open the file. Probably your program is looking for the file in a different place to what you think it should.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ifstream file; file.open("input.txt");` to `ifstream file("input.txt");`. Also, you don’t need to call `file.close()`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: The `good()` member isn't a good way to determine if the stream in a good state, unfortunately. In particular, it is a perfectly good state to have reached EOF without an error but `good()` still reports `false`. In you case the file couldn't be opened for reading which is most likely because the wrong path is used or, possibly, because you don't have read access. One way to rule out issues with the file is to use an absolute path to a file with a known location. Note that IDEs often execute the file in location which isn't necessarily the project root.

Comment: Note that `exit(1)` is not portable. There are three portable values for the argument to `exit`: `0` (which indicates successful execution), `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`.